# GIS map overlay intersection operation on map layers

Tags: dictionary, overlay, gis, geospatial, computational-geometry

In map overlay, is intersection of map layers a commutative operation ie layer_A intersection layer_B = layer_B intersection layer_A?

Comment: Isn't there a GIS specific exchange? http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if the layers are the same geometry type. If one layer is point, and the other line, for example, the intersection could be point or lines, and therefore it may not be commutative. If they are the same geometry type, then yes, operation of intersection is commutative.

Comment: didnot understand, for example if layer A is a square and layer B is a triangle. In this case, (A intersectn B) == (B intersectn A) ?

Comment: That is correct. Both are representable as polygons, so the result would be a polygonal layer representing the intersection of the two. Theoretically, these intersections are identical. In practice, however, due to rounding errors and limitation of using computational algorithms with floating point numbers, there could be small differences.